# Setting libreoffice UI font size in LO 6.1.5.2

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

How can I make the UI (menu bar in particular) font size larger? The [LO 6.0 user guide](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/1/17/GS6002-SettingUpLibreOffice.pdf), which seems to match the 6.1.5.2 interface, claims there's a "User Interface - Scaling" control under Tools / Options / LibreOffice / View - but there isn't, even in the [screenshot in the user guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzr08.gif). Just controls for icon size/style.

Comment: The menu bar size is normally a function of the operating system. I looked at the options above in LO 6.4 and changes there did not affect the menu bar.

Comment: I can see it being a function of whatever GUI toolkit (if any) LO uses, but it's definitely not a function of the Linux OS. I'm running WindowMaker, which is a very, very simple window manager, not a desktop environment like GNOME or KDE, and it's not in control of the GUI either.

Comment: I'm using LO 6.4 on Ubuntu 19.10 and do not see any option to scale the display. Am I missing something? Fonts on my LO toolbar are tiny.

Comment: This feature seems to be a matter of some contention -- see https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101646 .

Answer (score 2):

I think there are multiple answers to this question depending on OS.

In Linux, it seems to depend on whether one is using a desktop environment or not. https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/HiDpi claims life is good if one is using one of the more prominent desktop environments (e.g., GNOME or KDE).

If one is using LibreOffice under X with only a window manager, if the GTK UI is being used, try ensuring `libreoffice-gtk3` is installed (the package name in debian), setting GDK_SCALE, and then executing your favorite LibreOffice executable in that environment. For example, from the shell:

```
$ export GDK_SCALE=2
$ localc
```

Comment: That indeed works! Thanks very much. It also scales the content, not just the UI elements, but it's still a big improvement.

Comment: Actually, the libreoffice-gtk3 package seems to be the main source of improvement here. It definitely affects menu bar font size. After some poking around I realized that GTK_SCALE only supports integer scaling which makes the menu text if anything too enormous at scale 2. But the default GTK3 sizes are a big improvement and I'll take the win (also chimed in support on the documenfoundation.org Bugzilla noted above).

Comment: @user3124312 If fractional scaling is desired, you might take a stab at setting GDK_DPI_SCALE. I believe it supports fractional values. Haven't tested this myself, though (this whole issue has "tar pit" written all over it...).